# ngx-socket-io cannot connect to server because of unsupported protocol version

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building a web app with angular frontend and a NodeJs server on backend, both run on different places. I'm trying to use ngx-socket-io on angular to connect to my server but I have an error :

```
{
"code": 5,
"message": "Unsupported protocol version"}
```

on the browser console.

This is my code :

app-module.ts (Angular)

```js
...
import { IoRequestService } from './services/ioRequest.service'

import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8080', options: {transports: [ "websocket" ], withCredentials: true} };

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    GoogleChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    IoRequestService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Io service

```js
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class IoRequestService {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit("message", msg);
    console.log("msg send");
  }

  getMessage() {
        return this.socket
            .fromEvent("message")
            .pipe(map((data:any) => data.msg));
   }
}
```

use of io service :

```js
...
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  transactions: Transaction[] = [];
  constructor(private serviceIO: IoRequestService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  send() {
    console.log("button clicked");
    this.serviceIO.sendMessage("test");
  }

}
```

And nodeJS backend :

```js
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');



var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:4200",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
    allowEIO3: true
  }
});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'student',
  password : 'std___01',
  database : 'elevage'
});


app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('message', (socket)=> {
    console.log('I win the game');
  })
});

//handle unfound pages
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !');
});

server.listen(8080, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err);
  }
  console.log(`server is on`);
});
```

Any Idea what the problem is? I saw that people also use socket.io-client but ngx-socket-io seems way easier, maybe that's the issue but everything seems ok when I look at the docs.

There (https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/index.html) I found that issue may be solved by setting `allowEIO3: true`, but it didn't worked.
Or maybe it comes from the browser? I tried on both firefox and safari latest version and I have the same issue.

When I install the npm package, I had to force it. It may encounter issue because of the repesitories structures? which look like that :

- project
- angular-app

  - node_module (for Angular)
- nodejs-app
- node_module (for NodeJs)

Answer (score 0):

Are you requiered to use ngx-socket-io ?
I had the same issue and replaced it by **socket.io-client** version 3.1.2
It seems to work fine for me with this package.